# How to make a query that automatically create another column and convert date format?

Tags: mysql, database

I  have a date column attribute in my calendar_table where I store my date, I want to add another column `date_name` and then populate all of them automatically like below.

date: *2017-07-28* to `date_name` *28 July, Friday*

Currently using heidiSQL (MySQL)

I tried queries below but it say that there are syntax error

```
SELECT [date],
DATENAME(day, [date]) + ' ' + DATENAME(month, [date]) + ', ' + DATENAME(DW, [date])
FROM [dbo].[DatesTable]( -- current month calendar table
DATEADD(dd,1,EOMONTH (GETDATE(), -1)),
EOMONTH (GETDATE())
) 


 Select cd.date
 from calendar_table as cd
 INSERT into cd.date_name values (
 CAST(DATEPART(DAY,DateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,DateTime) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ','+ CAST(DATENAME(DAY,DateTime) AS VARCHAR(8)))
```

Comment: You seem to be using sql server syntax.

Comment: the above is MS SQL Server syntax. Consult the manual for your DBMS.

Comment: you can easily google the equivalent for each of the functions you're using. You don't need us to look it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a date from default format `yyyy-mm-dd` (example: `2017-07-28`) to any other *text* format like `28 July, Friday` you have to use [`DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

**Example**:

```
SELECT @dt:=CAST( '2017-07-28' AS DATE ) AS dt
     , DATE_FORMAT( @dt, '%d %M, %W' ) AS formatted_date_string
```

Output will be in the following format:

```
+------------+-----------------------+
| dt         | formatted_date_string |
+------------+-----------------------+
| 2017-07-28 | 28 July, Friday       |
+------------+-----------------------+
```

You can use same or similar format in your transactions.
But my suggestion is not to store formatted date strings into database but only date and times in their default formats. You can apply formats on those fields for views and prints.

Comment: how do i populate my entire date list column to that of that of formatted_date_string cause I have a big list of date.

Comment: use your table's date column in the place of `dt` in the given example

Comment: your query should be like `select date_col, date_format(date_col, ......) as formatted_d.... from table_name`

Comment: Shouldn't i use insert or update instead of select statement cause i want to populate my 'date_name' column like 28 July, Friday based on my other 'date' column where i already have values like that  2017-07-28

Comment: Something like that insert into calendar_table (date_name) values (DATE_FORMAT( date_name, '%d %M, %W' )); or that update calendar_table
set date_name = DATE_FORMAT( date_name, '%d %M, %W' )
where date_name = date_name; the 2nd example work if i populate my already date_name with value like 2017-07-28 first then convert them to the appropriate date-format

Comment: _**@JohnLaimuin**_: If you really need to insert or update you can follow the example given in the select statement. Let me hope `date_name` column is of `varchar` and you will apply `date_format` on actual `date` column but not `date_name` column. But again, please read my _suggestion_ given in the answer.